Replacing std::visit with mapbox's variant visit implementation
I'm currently downporting C++17 code to C++14. Since C++14 doesn't have variant I'm using the variant implementation by mapbox which is available here. Basically, substituting variant using mapbox::util::variant works fine but there's one thing I can't get to work and that is substituting the calls to std::visit with mapbox's ones. The original code looks like this:
std::string XLSheet::name() const
{
    return std::visit([](auto&& arg) { return arg.name(); }, m_sheet);
}

I've tried to rewrite the code like this:
std::string XLSheet::name() const
{
    return mapbox::util::variant::visit([](auto&& arg) { return arg.name(); }, m_sheet);
}

But it doesn't work. I'm getting the following error:
template <class ... Types> class mapbox::util::variant used without template parameters

So what am I supposed to pass as template parameters please? I'm not experienced with C++ at all. m_sheet is defined as mapbox::util::variant<XLWorksheet, XLChartsheet> m_sheet; so I've also tried to rewrite the code like this:
std::string XLSheet::name() const
{
    return mapbox::util::variant<XLWorksheet, XLChartsheet>::visit([](auto&& arg) { return arg.name(); }, m_sheet);
}

But then I'm getting the following error:
no matching function call to mapbox::util::variant<OpenXLSX::XLWorksheet, OpenXLSX::XLChartsheet>::visit()

Now I'm out of ideas. Can anybody help?

From the readme it looks like you want mapbox::util::apply_visitor(lambda, m_sheet);.

@HolyBlackCat Thanks, so the code should be this: return mapbox::util::apply_visitor([](auto&& arg) { return arg.name(); }, m_sheet); ?

I think so? That's from the first glance at the readme, I could be wrong.

Ok, it compiles. I don't really know what visitors are so I also can't tell if it's the correct way but looks promising since the manpage of std::visit also says that it applies the visitor to the variant so I think it makes sense for a substitute to be named apply_visitor...

@Andreas If that works, could you self-answer for future readers with how it worked exactly?

@Andreas that’s a naming convention taken from/shared with Boost. I prefer visit to apply_visitor but that’s just a matter of taste.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont Ok, done now

As suggested by HolyBlackCat in the comments above, the solution is simply to replace visit by apply_visitor, i.e.
std::string XLSheet::name() const
{
    return mapbox::util::apply_visitor([](auto&& arg) { return arg.name(); }, m_sheet);
}

This does the trick.
